# Mapkit Overlay image coordinate

Tags: iphone, mapkit, overlay

I have added an imageview on top of mapview.
Now, i would like to get the location coordinate where the image is overlay on, whenever the map is moved.

How do i do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This delegate will be useful to you

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
```

Source:[MKMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)